# how php sorting in looping while mysql_fetch_assoc?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

this my query:

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from people order by birth asc");
while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $birth=$r['birth'];
    if($r['addmonth']=="2") {
        $birth=date("d-m-Y", strtotime("$birth+2 month")); //additional months on date of birth
    }

    echo"$r[name] $birth";
}
```

how to sort with php returned by the $birth ASC

Comment: if you are adding 2 months to every `$birth`, wouldn't it keep the sort the same way? Also, if you are just echoing the dates, not storing them, it is not possible to go back and resort. Could you show an example of what you are currently getting versus what you want?

Comment: thanks for the response but my question is I mean update

Comment: @Sean It could be possible with OB, but that's definitely not the right approach

Comment: So some of the `$birth` values will be increased by `+2 month`, and then after you want to resort all of the rows again. Is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your query to increase the months at the DB, so you won't need to order the rows again:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN (addmonth = 2) THEN (birth + INTERVAL 2 MONTH) ELSE (birth) END AS birth_order FROM people ORDER BY birth_order ASC
```

---

Edit:

Another option is to retrieve the array without change at the SQL, and use [`usort`](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.usort.php):

```
$people = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY birth ASC");

if ($result) {
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $people []= $r;
    }

    mysql_free_result($result);
}

$calculate_date = function ($person) {
    $date = $person['birth'];

    if ($person['addmonth'] == 2) {
        $date += '+2 month';
    }

    return $date;
};

usort($people,function($a,$b)use($calculate_date){
    return $calculate_date($a) > $calculate_date($b);
});
```

Comment: thanks your answer is correct but the actual condition of its program a lot and can not be overcome with a mysql query. could result in the sort back with php?